# python pandas to SQL server Error overload columns

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

i am trying this code

```
df = pandas.read_sql_table(details)
df.to_sql(details)
```

meaning i tried to take a table and just put it back in SQL in a new name and i have tried do some manipulation on the table but still i got the same error:

```
programmingError
\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self , dialect , constructor , statement , parameters , *args)
line 1192     parameters ,
line -> 1193     context)
line 1194     except BaseException as e

..\enging\defaulte.py
line 506 def do_execute(self , cursor , statment , parmetrs , context)
line 507 cursor.execute(statment , parametrs)
```

and 
programmingError : ('the SQL containe 12366 parameters  marks , but 77902 parameters were supplied' , 'HY000')

and

```
DBAPIError :(pyodoc.Error) ('[07002] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectw) [SQL : 'INSERT INTO [testName] ([index] , [col1] , [col2] ... [colN]) VALUES (? , ? , ? ,...?) , (? , ? , ? ,...?) , (? , ? , ? ,...?) , (? , ? , ? ,...?) ... (? , ? , ? ,...?)]')
the number of ? , ? is N times as the col number and the (? , ? , ? ,...?) is as the number of the rows.
```

when i tried the same code on smaller table or when i dived this table two table with less the 7 cols this load and update perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've hit an internal limit on the number of bind parameters in a SQL statement within SQL Server or the driver used to connect to it.  Interestingly, `77902 - 12366 == 65536 == 2**16`, which makes me think that a 16-bit integer somewhere has overflowed.

Fortunately there seems to be a parameter in the `to_sql` method that you can use to break the SQL statements into chunks rather than sending the lot in one go.  From the [Pandas documentation for `to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

> **chunksize** : *int, optional*
>
> Rows will be written in batches of this size at a time. By default, all rows will be written at once.

The total number of parameters (77902) factorises as 2 × 11 × 3541, with 3541 being prime.  It looks like your table has either 11 columns and 7082 rows or 22 columns and 3541 rows.  To avoid this error I would recommend keeping the number of bind parameters in a chunk below 32767 just in case the 16-bit integer I suspect to be causing this problem is signed, so `chunksize=1000` would probably work for you.  At the same time, however, this is unlikely to give much faster performance than `chunksize=100` so it's not worth spending that much time trying to find the largest chunk size that will work.

Comment: the only things the work if i split the df to small won with 6 cols